# Scrapy Spider not scraping correctly

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Python.org 2.7 64 bit shell on Windows Vista. I have Scrapy installed and it seems to be stable and working. However, I have copied the following simple piece of code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "craig"
        allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
        start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/sfc/npo/"]

        def parse(self, response):
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            titles = hxs.select("//p")
            for titles in titles:
                title = titles.select("a/text()").xpath()
                link = titles.select("a/@href").xpath()
                print title, link
```

Contained in this Youtube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EFnX1UkXVU
When I run this code I get the warning:

```
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\spiders\test.py:11: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead.
  titles = hxs.select("//p")
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\selector\unified.py:106: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector is deprecated, ins
.Selector instead.
  for x in result]
C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\spiders\test.py:13: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead.
  title = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\spiders\test.py:14: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function select. Use .xpath() instead.
  link = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
```

Has some of the syntax of Scrapy changed recently so that .extract() is no longer valid? I've tried using .xpath() instead, but this throws up an error saying that two arguments are required for .xpath(), but I'm not sure what to use there.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html. It also contains examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reference to the other answer, it should be

```
title = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `extract` thats wrong (`extract` is still valid), it's the `select`. The selector API has recently changed as *1478963* mentioned in a comment (as time's running so fast, *recently* could have been one year or so already...).

We do not use the `HtmlXPathSelector` anymore, but instead a general `Selector` which includes methods for both `xpath()` and `css()`. Using Selector you can choose between both and especially also mix both just by calling the one or the other method.

Your example in new code should look like this (untested):

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/sfc/npo/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.selector.xpath("//p")
        for titles in titles:
            title = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            link = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
            print title, link
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. so the syntax for selector has changed rather than the format of the website im am experimenting with? when i tried your code example, the following was printed to the log: <bound method SelectorList.extract of []> [u'/sfc/npo/4551729953.html']
<bound method SelectorList.extract of []> [u'/sfc/npo/4551720521.html']
<bound method SelectorList.extract of []> [u'/sfc/npo/4551672867.html']
<bound method SelectorList.extract of []> [u'/sfc/npo/4551668469.html']

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this (Tested). Aufziehvogel's code got me 95% there.

```
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

    class MySpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "craig"
        allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
        start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo"]

        def parse(self, response):
            titles = response.selector.xpath("//p")
            items = []
            for titles in titles:
                item = CraigslistSampleItem()
                item["title"] = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
                item["link"] = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
                items.append(item)
            return items
```