# Scrapy Spider not returning all elements

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

Newbie to Programming/Python36. OS: Windows 10

I wrote a spider in Scrapy and my json file returns only some of the values. It makes me think that the xpath syntax is correct but I cannot seem to find what's wrong.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560395/scrapy-spider-not-scraping-correctly) was not a help at all since this is not the issue with my code snippet.

Code+Output:

Code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class OfriSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ofri"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ofri.ch/firmen"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.ofri.ch/firmen/Abbruchunternehmen/']

    def parse(self, response):
        entries_description = response.xpath('//div[@class="directory-entry"]//div[@class="directory-entry-description"]')
        for entry_description in entries_description:
            company_name = entry_description.xpath('.//h2/a/text()').extract()
            address_street = entry_description.xpath('.//p[@itemprop="address"]/span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]/text()').extract()
            zip_locality = entry_description.xpath('.//p[@itemprop="address"]/span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract()
            contact_data = entry_description.xpath('.//*[@id="business_directory_contact_data"]/div/ul').extract_first()
            tel = entry_description.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="telephone"]//text()').extract()
            company_url = entry_description.xpath('.//a[@itemprop="url"]/@href').extract()
            yield{'name':company_name,
                  'street':address_street,
                  'zip_locality':zip_locality,
                  'tel':tel,
                  'url':company_url}
```

Output

```
[
,
{"name": ["Eugen Schnabel Transport & Transfer"], "street": ["Talstrasse 24"], "zip_locality": ["8885 Mols"], "tel": ["0041767198236"], "url": []},
,
,
{"name": ["Hanna-reinigung"], "street": ["Schlierenstrasse 48"], "zip_locality": ["8902 Urdorf"], "tel": ["0799481971"], "url": []},
,
{"name": ["Malergesch\u00e4ft Peic"], "street": ["Affolternstrasse 60"], "zip_locality": ["8105 Regensdorf"], "tel": ["0764824149"], "url": []},
,
,
,
,
{"name": ["Einzelfirma, Michael Heidelberger"], "street": ["Dorfstrasse 151"], "zip_locality": ["8424 Embrach"], "tel": ["0787907234"], "url": []},
{"name": ["ASS Immo + Bau GmbH"], "street": ["Tretteliweg 3b"], "zip_locality": ["8305 Dietlikon"], "tel": ["0764029370"], "url": []},
,
,
{"name": ["Baumontagen R. Schneiter"], "street": ["Jonenbachstrasse 7"], "zip_locality": ["8911 Rifferswil"], "tel": ["0796552188"], "url": []},
{"name": ["Plus Bau & GU GmbH"], "street": ["Wiesentrasse 83"], "zip_locality": ["3014 Bern"], "tel": ["0763462153"], "url": []},
,
,

]
```

Anyone spots what's wrong here?

Comment: I ran your spider and it isn't getting the information you are showing.

Comment: I run spider and I get all data. Linux Mint 18.2, Python 3.6.2, Scrapy 1.4.0

Comment: @eLRuLL what information are you getting? All the results on the page just or more/less?
Thanks for taking the time to run the spider.

Comment: @RichardPoe all the data, and also not formatted, maybe the code you are not sharing that is formatting the data is also deleting some.

Comment: @furas thank you. Strangely enough the above result was what I was getting on a Windows 10 machine with Python  3.6.0 and Scrapy 1.4.0. So only the OS is different.

Comment: @eLRuLL so from what I understood the pipelines.py is responsible for manipulating data and then outputting, correct? That's all there is:
`class OfriChPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
`
For completion also item.py:
`import scrapy


class OfriChItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass`
settings.py
`BOT_NAME = 'ofri_ch'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['ofri_ch.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'ofri_ch.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
`

Comment: maybe there are some differences in other part of code - I put all code (as standalone script which you can run without project) on GitHub - see [scraping/ofri.ch](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/__scraping__/ofri.ch/main.py)

Comment: btw: better put code in question - it will be more readable.

Comment: @furas your code is working!
I applied your way of defining the item variable first and the yielding the item and it works.
Now idea how exactly this is different though. Do you have any explanation by any chance?

Comment: you could use `print()` to display your item before you yield - to see if there is difference. But maybe there are differnces in config or you use some pipeline module which makes problem.

Comment: @furas I think it has been the yield and maybe bad formatting (no spaces etc.) ?
However, if you'll post an answer I can accept yours and we don't have to keep on posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your code and create standalone version which doesn't use any other files in project - and it has no problem to get all data.

Maybe problem is in setting or other files if you created project.

In some places I changed `extract()` into `extract_first()` because there was always single element.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    allowed_domains = ['www.ofri.ch/firmen']
    start_urls = ['http://www.ofri.ch/firmen/Abbruchunternehmen/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        entries_description = response.xpath('//div[@class="directory-entry"]//div[@class="directory-entry-description"]')

        for entry_description in entries_description:
            company_name = entry_description.xpath('.//h2/a/text()').extract_first()
            address_street = entry_description.xpath('.//p[@itemprop="address"]/span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]/text()').extract_first()
            zip_locality = entry_description.xpath('.//p[@itemprop="address"]/span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract_first()
            contact_data = entry_description.xpath('.//*[@id="business_directory_contact_data"]/div/ul').extract_first()
            tel = entry_description.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="telephone"]//text()').extract_first()
            company_url = entry_description.xpath('.//a[@itemprop="url"]/@href').extract_first()

            item = {
                'name': company_name,
                'street': address_street,
                'zip_locality': zip_locality,
                'tel': tel,
                'url':company_url
            }    

            print(item)

            yield item


# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Result:

```
[
{"name": "SZ.AC Team", "street": "Aadorferstrasse 19", "zip_locality": "8362 Balterswil", "tel": "0719601976", "url": "http://allesuntereinemdach.ch"},
{"name": "Eugen Schnabel Transport & Transfer", "street": "Talstrasse 24", "zip_locality": "8885 Mols", "tel": "0041767198236", "url": null},
{"name": "Glarner Rueckbau", "street": "Reimen 1", "zip_locality": "8775 H\u00e4tzingen", "tel": "0794017852", "url": "http://glarner-rueckbau-klg.ch"},
{"name": "Poldeschtrans", "street": "Talgasse 21", "zip_locality": "5503 Schafisheim", "tel": "0764414732", "url": "http://poldesch.ch"},
{"name": "Hanna-reinigung", "street": "Schlierenstrasse 48", "zip_locality": "8902 Urdorf", "tel": "0799481971", "url": null},
{"name": "FREUDENBERG HANDWERK UND INSTALLATIONSSERVICE", "street": "Bahnhofstrasse 2", "zip_locality": "4543 Deitingen", "tel": "0762872322", "url": "http://freudenberg-handwerk.ch"},
{"name": "Malergesch\u00e4ft Peic", "street": "Affolternstrasse 60", "zip_locality": "8105 Regensdorf", "tel": "0764824149", "url": null},
{"name": "Linsin Bau", "street": "M\u00fcllerweg 1", "zip_locality": "4633 Hauenstein", "tel": "0041793390620", "url": "http://Linsin-Bau.ch"},
{"name": "Sanimpex GmbH", "street": "Badenerstrasse 549", "zip_locality": "8048 Z\u00fcrich", "tel": "0432109670", "url": "http://sanimpex.ch"},
{"name": "M.Spangenberg", "street": "Kronenweg.3", "zip_locality": "8165 Oberweningen", "tel": "0434228168", "url": "http://spangenberg-kundenmaurer.ch"},
{"name": "M. Johann Tiefbau", "street": "Bahnhofstrasse 2", "zip_locality": "6162 Entlebuch", "tel": "0415303406", "url": "http://johann-tiefbau.ch"},
{"name": "Einzelfirma, Michael Heidelberger", "street": "Dorfstrasse 151", "zip_locality": "8424 Embrach", "tel": "0787907234", "url": null},
{"name": "ASS Immo + Bau GmbH", "street": "Tretteliweg 3b", "zip_locality": "8305 Dietlikon", "tel": "0764029370", "url": null},
{"name": "tm rent Gmbh", "street": "Im Ebnet 66", "zip_locality": "8700 K\u00fcsnacht", "tel": "0764148714", "url": "http://www.tm-rent.ch"},
{"name": "HBS Bau GmbH", "street": "Eisenbahnstrasse 18", "zip_locality": "8730 Uznach", "tel": "0797343583", "url": "http://hbs-bau.ch"},
{"name": "Baumontagen R. Schneiter", "street": "Jonenbachstrasse 7", "zip_locality": "8911 Rifferswil", "tel": "0796552188", "url": null},
{"name": "Plus Bau & GU GmbH", "street": "Wiesentrasse 83", "zip_locality": "3014 Bern", "tel": "0763462153", "url": null},
{"name": "Ettlin Mont-& Demontagen", "street": "Untere Gr\u00fcndlistrasse 20", "zip_locality": "6055 Alpnach Dorf", "tel": "0794121162", "url": "http://ettlin-montagen.ch"},
{"name": "ISISERVICE", "street": "Tiefenaustrasse 131", "zip_locality": "3004 Bern", "tel": "0313815488", "url": "http://isiservice.ch"},
{"name": "S & G Services GmbH", "street": "Mutschellenstrasse 85", "zip_locality": "8038 Z\u00fcrich", "tel": "0762502222", "url": "http://sg-reinigung.ch"}
]
```

Answer (score -2):

Your Xpath is correct as far as I checked, you can verify your main xpath using chrome:

`$x('//div[@class="directory-entry"]//div[@class="directory-entry-description"]');`

So the problem should be somewhere else, could be different div contents.

Except for the url one (it's getting the object, rather than the url value), eg, look at the result of:

`$x('//div[@class="directory-entry"]//div[@class="directory-entry-description"]//a[@itemprop="url"]/@href');`
in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the url out. I obviously forgot the `.extract()` at the end.
For the rest I did check the xpath in the scrapy shell and it worked fine. There must've been something wrong with the tuple.